# Python PyWebView - Blank page on my Mac when try to loads any external item outside my localhost

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, pywebview

I'm trying to execute a PyWebView example from this repo: https://github.com/r0x0r/pywebview
I'm using the Flask Example: https://github.com/r0x0r/pywebview/tree/master/examples/flask_app

When I try to load or interact with external item out of my localhost, the PyWebView appears as blank like don't load anything. When I comment or exclude any element that refers a online content, the window opens normally.

It doesn't matter if my content is an image, or a CSS Google Fonts, or trying to call an external authentication, the system doesn't work anyway.

I tried the same code in a Windows PC and it works normally.
I tried http and https and in both cases the problem was the same.

I'm using a Macbook Pro M1, Ventura 13 and I don't have firewall or VPS.

Thanks

I've tried in Windows and It Works.
I've tried in Mac again switching off all references from external elements and the system worked normally in both platforms.